# How do I let ert know where my tests are defined?

Tags: ert, testing

**What I'm doing:**

If I define a test like:

```
(ert-deftest tmp-test ()   
  "failing test"   
  :expected-result :failed
  (should (eql (+ 1 0) 2)))
```

and then I run

```
M-x ert-run-tests-automatically ;; with selector t
```

My cursor jumps to the `*ert*` test buffer and I can view the failing test

```
f tmp-test
    failing test
    (ert-test-failed
     ((should
       (eql
        (+ 1 0)
        2))
      :form
      (eql 1 2)
      :value nil))
```

However when I move my cursor over the "tmp-test" link and press enter instead of switching windows/buffers and jumping the cursor to the test definition like I assume should happen I see the message 
`"Don't know where 'tmp-test' is defined"` printed in the minibuffer.

**Question:**

How do I tell ert where to find my test definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this depends on *how* you did the "I define a test like".  More specifically it depends if you do it by loading a file that contains this test or if you use `M-:` or `M-C-x`.

More specifically, it *should* work if you `M-x load-file` the file that contains the test, whereas I'm not surprised if it doesn't work when you define it via something like `M-C-x` or `M-:` or `C-x C-e`.

Comment: Yep, that was it. running load-file allows me to jump to the test like I expected.